# PostGIS : Update a POINT (geometry) with a POINT from another table with the same SRID

Tags: postgis, update

I try to update a geometry point with data from another table (also a geometry point).
Both are SRID 4326.
The query is executing without errors, everything is updated but the geometry is just not updated.

Do I have to transform first to lat lng and then back again?
Is it not possible to use a geometry type?
I don't get it at the moment.

Example:

```
UPDATE location
    SET
    location_name = import_ogr.location_name,
    location_category_id = import_ogr.location_category_id::INTEGER,
    position_geo = import_ogr.wkb_geometry
    FROM importexport.import_ogr
    WHERE location.location_id = 23017;
```

Comment: Is your data in WKB like the name suggest or is a geometry ? Maybe try ST_GeomFromWKB

Comment: Are you sure that the `import_ogr` geometry is not null? If it was a format/type issue, an error would have been thrown. Since other fields are updated, it means that either the source geometry is null or that there is a trigger on the `location` table that prevents geometry update.

Comment: Also do note that you are not specifying a join condition between the two tables, so unless there is a single record in the `import_ogr` table, the query is using a random row for the update

Comment: The data is made by ogr2ogr. In pgAdmin i see no difference between the 2 tables, but i'm not an expert. With  ST_GeomFromWKB :
WARNING:  OGC WKB expected, EWKB provided - use GeometryFromEWKB():
UPDATE 1
Query returned successfully

WARNING:  OGC WKB expected, EWKB provided - use GeometryFromEWKB() for this
UPDATE 1

Query returned successfully 

With GeometryFromEWKB() it's also  
Query returned successfully

But the Point is not updated (Without error and all the other data are updated)
Can it be a rights problem? With pgAdmin the geo column is locked with a lock symbol

Comment: JGH! Your^'re right! It was the trigger! Thx for this eye opener!

Answer (score 1):

I had a trigger that updated the geo column with:

```
position_geo = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(NEW.lng,NEW.lat), 4326)
```

when updating lat and lng. That's preventing from updating the column.